# Good practice to populate iphone tableview array in previous view?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsarray

I have a quick question regarding populating a UITableView's array.

I have a login screen, and after successful login, the next view is a tableview of items that must be queried from a database.  I have a webservice set up that does the querying and returns an xml formatted string of all of the items.

Would it be more a better idea to connect with the webservice and fill out an array in the login view, and then pass that to the succeeding tableview?  This way I can show an indicator progress spinner while its logging in, and populating the next view...

Or to just do this in the viewDidLoad() method of the tableview?

Thanks!

Comment: Personally I would opt to pre-load in the login page.

Answer (score 0):

Makes sense to load it at login during the authentication. I'd also recommend saving some information locally if possible to reduce the wait time to the table view.

Comment: Can you expand on that... what would I store locally?

Comment: depends on what your app does. I one of the app that I am working on, the user has different images that he/she "liked" in the past. This is something I keep locally in order not to re download them again next time this user logs in or launches the app

Comment: I noticed on the Facebook app that after login, it immediately takes you to the next view, however the middle of the screen is blank, and has an indicator progress spinner...  How would I implement that?... the population of the array would not be in the viewDidLoad() method since the view is already loaded...

Comment: it's not what i am seeing...when you sign in on facebook app, it shows you a loader on the sign in page, then takes you to the feed screen (which is blank for a few moments)